# Grammar in .NET CultureInfo/RegionInfo

Tags: c#, .net

I have a sentence "It looks like you are from {{country}}" where {{country}} is getting it's value from RegionInfo.EnglishName. This works fine for countries like Sweden and Denmark, but it will be grammatically incorrect for countries where you put "the" in front of the name as their names in RegionInfo are without the "the".

For example:

- The United States
- The United Kingdom

As far as I can tell neither CultureInfo nor RegionInfo contain a name field which includes "The".

Obviously I could try to reword the sentence, but does the .NET framework contain this information at all and if not, how would I solve the problem in a good way?

Comment: Build your own dictionary where the key is `CultureInfo` and the value is String.

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I'm hoping not to have to do.

Comment: Not many functions are returning grammatically correct text (if any tbh). They aren't designed for this. Their purpose is to give *value*. You would typically use them (in multi-language application): `"Country: {0}"`. Whenever you need *language-specific* text - it's usually a translation build into application which will only work for languages supported by application.

Comment: Probably, you have just to create a small dictionary/hashset of *exceptions* (countries with *the*), i.e. *The Bahamas, The Gambia, The United Kingdom, The United States* and test if given `CultureInfo` is a key in this dictionary/hashset

Comment: @DmitryBychenko From what I have read, the list seems to be not-very-stable and not fixed. While *The United States* is correct, [Ucraine is both The Ucraine and Ucraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_of_Ukraine)